# Building Multi-Module Mercury Programs

Tags: mercury

Q. What's a simple template for building a two-module mercury program? Module_1 defines and exports a simple function or predicate. Module_2 imports the function/predicate to compute a useful result and outputs the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the following approach, first define the module with the 
function(s) or predicate(s) or predicates you want to export (interface section):

```
% File: gcd.m

:- module gcd.

:- interface.
:- import_module integer.

:- func gcd(integer, integer) = integer.

:- implementation.

:- pragma memo(gcd/2).
gcd(A, B) = (if B = integer(0) then A else gcd(B, A mod B)).
```

The file using the exported function in the gcd module (gcd/2):

```
% File: test_gcd.m

:- module test_gcd.

:- interface.

:- import_module io.

:- pred main(io::di, io::uo) is det.

:- implementation.

:- import_module char.
:- import_module gcd.
:- import_module integer.
:- import_module list.
:- import_module std_util.
:- import_module string.

main(!IO) :-
    command_line_arguments(Args, !IO),
    ArgToInteger = integer.det_from_string `compose` list.det_index0(Args),

    A = ArgToInteger(0),
    B = ArgToInteger(1),

    Fmt = (func(Integer) = s(integer.to_string(Integer))),
    GCD = gcd(A, B),
    io.format("gcd(%s, %s) = %s\n", list.map(Fmt, [A, B, GCD]), !IO).
```

To compile and run on Windows (cmd.exe):
Please note that mmc is also a Windows system command, so please use the
Mercury environment provided by the Mercury distribution installer:

```
> mmc --use-grade-subdirs -m test_gcd
> test_gcd 12 4
```

To compile and run on Linux/MacOS/etc (any Bash-like shell):

```
$ mmc --use-grade-subdirs -m test_gcd
$ ./test_gcd 12 4
```

Comment: You should be able to use the "mmc" command on windows.  (We encourage this).

Comment: Thanks @PaulBone, I reworded the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I read the Mercury User's Guide and learned the following:

$ "mmc -f module_1.m module_2.m"    % without the quotes

$ "mmake module_2.depend"

$ "mmake module_2"

It built an executable, module_2, which I executed

$ "./module_2"

and it worked properly. When all else fails, read the manual.

Comment: I've to say that the User Guide is a little bit outdated in this approach, from my experience as a Mercury beginner it is easier to exploit the automatic dependency detection of the `mmc` compiler using the `--make` flag, as I've demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: Sebastian is correct.  mmake is deprecated and when we introduce new features we don't ad them to mmake.

mmc -f is not deprecated, but it is only useful when your file names don't match your module names, or when modules are placed in directories other than the current directory.

Thanks.