# Building a Mercury program with sub-modules in a subdirectory

Tags: mercury

I have a mercury program that imports a module from another file. I'd like to be able to put this file in a subdirectory. How can I do this?

I'm using `mmc -E --make --trace deep filename` to make the program.

I've looked at [Building Multi-Module Mercury Programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825338/building-multi-module-mercury-programs) but it doesn't seem to deal with the subdirectory issue, although I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `mmc -f list of mercury files` option from the directory where you want to import the file in the sub-directory. This will create a Mercury.modules file that helps `mmc -m` to resolve all modules